# Has President Trump stated why he sought Ukraine's cooperation on the Biden matter?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, ukraine, joe-biden

Has Trump given an explanation (himself or through a spokesperson) for asking Ukraine to cooperate with finding things about Biden's son?

Given that the transcript of the phone call to the President of Ukraine has been released, has President Trump given any explanation about his motives for doing that request?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question or to debate topics which are unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but [a tweet President Trump put out on September 30th 2019](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1178670564879343619) looks like an answer to your question. From what I can see, though, it's not a reply to any other tweet or question, it's merely a statement. I'll let the text speak for itself (emphasis mine):

> Very simple! **I was looking for Corruption** and also why Germany, France and others in the European Union don’t do more for Ukraine. Why is it always the USA that does so much and puts up so much money for Ukraine and other countries? By the way, the Bidens were corrupt!

I interpret the first of the second sentence (in bold) as the reason for his request for cooperation. I think the part I emphasised refers to the Biden because the end of the tweet directly states the *"the Bidens were corrupt!"*.

Comment: You should probably note that Trump's claims are a deliberate misinterpretation of the facts and there is no evidence that Biden used his office to protect his son. The answers to this [question on skeptics.se](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/45017/44768) explain better than I can

Comment: @divibisan yes, this quote of President Trump (or indeed any other text I quote) should not be construed as support for or an endorsement of the entity making the statement nor the content thereof unless otherwise stated. I didn't think such a disclaimer was necessary, but it's better to be safe than sorry, I guess. This quote is merely used to indicate how the president has chosen to justify his actions to the public. Indeed it answers the question and it's a common tactic to try to discredit political opponents using *trumped-up* corruption charges.

Comment: "No evidence that Biden used his office to protect his son"--Like when he bragged about extorting Ukraine to fire the prosecutor investigating his son in exchange for $1B dollars? https://americanmilitarynews.com/2019/09/video-of-a-bragging-biden-trading-1-billion-in-ukraine-aid-for-official-firing-resurfaces-amid-trump-flap/

Comment: This is a good and fairly direct answer. He clearly states he was looking for corruption, and found it.